# getting error when try to get user by id ------> (localhost:3080/api/users/?id=1) cannot get /api/user/id=1 error

Tags: javascript, node.js

but i getting all users but by id didnt working

[
{
"firstName": "myname",
"lastName": "notimp",
"email": "myname@gmail.com",
"textbox": "this pc",
"Imgupload_date": "2020-07-13T07:36:44.117Z",
"Image_name": "Screenshot.png",
"id": "1"
},
{
"firstName": "hello",
"lastName": "world",
"email": "helloworld@gmail.com",
"textbox": "this pc",
"Imgupload_date": "2021-07-13T07:36:44.117Z",
"Image_name": "Screenshot 2021-07-13 130641.png",
"id": "2"
}
]

i need only id=1 user

```js
app.get('/api/user', (req, res) => {
  console.log('api/user called!!!!!!!')
  const databuffer = fs.readFileSync('user.json', 'utf8')
  const datajson = databuffer.toString()
  const dtafil = JSON.parse(datajson);
  res.json(dtafil);
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with you question. Like What are you trying to do and what did you get

Comment: [
  {
    "firstName": "myname",
    "lastName": "notimp",
    "email": "myname@gmail.com",
    "textbox": "this pc",
    "Imgupload_date": "2020-07-13T07:36:44.117Z",
    "Image_name": "Screenshot.png",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "hello",
    "lastName": "world",
    "email": "helloworld@gmail.com",
    "textbox": "this pc",
    "Imgupload_date": "2021-07-13T07:36:44.117Z",
    "Image_name": "Screenshot 2021-07-13 130641.png",
    "id": "2"
  }
]

Comment: when i need only id=1 user

Comment: Ok this is the JSON data in the file user.json right. Now what are you trying to do?

Comment: Save the json data with id as the index. Then it will be much more easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by `/?...`You need to extract data from query parameters.
for example for `api/users/?id=1`:

```
app.get('api/users/', async function(req, res) {
    let id= req.query.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get parameters from the url you need to set up the endpoint to get it.

[This](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) part of the expressjs docs explains how to do that.

Comment: this could have been a comment instead of answer. As answer should be detailed having code snippet.

Comment: he was asking how to do something that is clearly explained in the official docs